# how to get table rows select option value using checkbox

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following html table with select option in one of the columns. I want to display the values of the rows that are checked but don't know how to work with the select option value. Can someone help me modify the code? If not using DOM, can we just use PHP to get all checked values and store in $ variable? Finally I will submit the checked values and insert into table using PHP. Thanks a lot.

```
<?php
require_once("connMysql.php");
$stu_add = mysqli_query($db_link, "SELECT * FROM stu");
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($stu_add);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>how to get options value in html table</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align:center; width:70px">Classname</th>
    <th style="text-align:center; width:100px">Student ID</th>        
    <th style="text-align:center; width:100px">Name</th>
    <th style="text-align:center; width:100px">Grade</th>
    <th style="text-align:center; width:100px">Select</th>        
    </tr>
   <?php
   if($stu_add-> num_rows > 0 ){
    while ($row = $stu_add-> fetch_assoc()){
   ?>
   <tr>
    <td id="classname" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['classname'];?></td>
    <td id="stuid" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['stuid'];?></td>        
    <td id="stu_name" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['stu_name'];?></td>
    <td><select name="grade" id="grade">
        <option value="">-Please select-</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checked" name="checked[]" value="<?php echo $row['stuid'];?>">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <?php
   }
   }
   ?>
  <input type="text" id="classname" size="10">
  <input type="text" id="stuid" size="10">
  <input type="text" id="stu_name" size="10">
  <input type="text" id="grade" size="10">
  <button class="" onclick="showData()">Show data</button>
  </table>
  <script>
    function showData()
    {
        var table = document.getElementById('table');
        for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
        {
            table.rows[i].onclick = function()
            {
                // document.getElementById("classname").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                // document.getElementById("stuid").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                // document.getElementById("stu_name").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                // document.getElementById("grade").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML.options[0].text;

                var a = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                var b  = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                var c  = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                var d  = this.cells[3].innerHTML.options[0].text;
                var data = a + b + c + d;
                alert(data);
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you cant really access the checkbox values from the php code once rendered unless you make additional requests(say `onchange`) to let the code know that. You might want to look at AJAX on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

As the above user says you can get the id of the checkbox and use onchange then pass the value to the function.

````
```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
          var query = $(this).val();
showdata(query);
    });
```
````